cudf ModuleNotFoundError after installing RAPIDS in MSL2
I successfully installed RAPIDS in my WSL2 window, but importing cudf is not working. According to the RAPIDS website https://docs.rapids.ai/install#conda , as well as some other sources, I should be able to import cudf on the spot. Right? See image below. I completed step 5 - verified by the fact the window tells me "a conda environment already exists..."-, but step 6 doesn't work.

Below is the WSL2 including an image of the same thing that's easier to view. How do I import cudf?
(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ ls
Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh    Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64.exe    anaconda3
Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Linux-x86_64.sh.1  Anaconda3-2024.06-1-Windows-x86_64.exe.1
(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ conda create -n rapids-24.06 -c rapidsai -c conda-forge -c nvidia  \
    rapids=24.06 python=3.11 'cuda-version>=12.0,<=12.2'
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at '/home/aridleprechaun/anaconda3/envs/rapids-24.06'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? n


CondaSystemExit: Exiting.

(base) aridleprechaun@Samuel-Tanner-Desktop:~$ python
Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:12:24) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cudf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cudf'
>>> import pandas



(Image representation below):


Before using Python, you'll need to activate the conda environment you created.

You're totally right. I literally just discovered this seconds ago when I reinstalled. Do you know if powershell-like environment is the only IDE for cudf? I'm going to research how to get this into jupyter notebooks, but it would be nice to be told if i'm going on a wild goose chase.

conda activate rapids-24.06
How I discovered it:
I discovered this answer by going back and deleting the extra "items" (sorry i don't know what to call them) listed by ls. I then re-installed RAPIDS- I selected "y" to overwrite-, and the resulting installation provided me with instructions: "To activate this enviornment, use conda activate rapids-24.06. Now i just need to figure out how to get this all to be in my jupyter notebooks instead of a very inconvenient terminal window, I'll be golden. Problem stated is solved, at least.


For moving to your notebook, you have two options. (1) Read the top two scoring answers here and decide which one you want to try. You may be able to already connect the environment you made in your terminal to your Jupyter session. (2) Execute the conda install commands you worked out in a running notebook, prefacing them with the magic symbol % (& optionally pass yes so you don't have to type later), so they'd start  ``%conda install or%conda install  --yes ...`. (The latter means you install in one more place but is convenient.)
